# Whats the best way to do this in cakephp

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, cakephp

I'm new to cakephp and still learning my way through php in general. To learn I'm trying to build an app which allows the following:
- A user can sign up (using the basic Auth component)
- A signed up user can create a 'campaign', ie fill in a form which will end-up as a page on my website containing details of things the user is trying to achieve. As well as that there will be a 'story' field in the form for the user to explain the reason they are trying to achieve whatever it is they are doing.

Users will have different reasons for creating their campaign, ie new years resolution/wife nagged you into doing it/need to make more money etc etc...

To help users along what I'd like is to have some default stories written and via a radio button users can select their default template to edit. In other words, if they select the 'new years resolution' template a pre-written story will appear in the text box for the story field which they can edit to their preference before submitting.

As I said, Im new to cakephp but have bought all the books and read the manual a couple of times, but since I'm also a bit green with php too I'm struggling a bit. But whats the best way to go about doing the above?

If someone could give me a bit of a break down so I can go off and google the correct things then it would sure make this learning curve a whole lot less daunting.

thanks in advance
pete
ireland

Answer (score 1):

[Sorry to be so blunt but] It's pretty tough to answer this since you don't really have a specific problem but a general problem: you don't know the tools you want to work with.

Again, I don't mean you no harm.

For PHP in general, I would probably suggest to keep http://docs.php.net open in your browser at any time. PHP has one of the best (or maybe the best) language reference and manual. It probably also doesn't hurt to buy a book - IMHO, one from O'Reilly is usually a good fit.

As for CakePHP, I'd recommend starting here: http://cakephp.org/#learn

What you need to do is learn the framework and then go from there. Learn and adapt. There's no other way. What you described is of course not specifically part of any of the tutorials or screencast, but they teach you the skills necessary to achieve your own goals.

Comment: when you are more comfortable with cake and php in general, figure out your database. It will be the main point that decides what your app can or cant do.

Comment: cheers for the advice, no harm taken ;) like I said I've bought all four books and read the manual twice. I guess what I'm looking for is a bit of a road map, I don't need to know that I need to create this table, that controller and this model etc etc, more like you said, those tutorials don't have exactly this situation in them and short of reading the books again to find the bit that gives me the insight I was hoping someone could give me a: do this b:then this c:then hey presto

Comment: just to clarify a little. I know I'm going to have to go and learn a lot of stuff to actually be able to do what I want, I just want to know what bits I should be looking at. Like for this you need to read up on xxxx

Comment: I think the CakePHP tutorials do really well because they help you learn the framework fast.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like I am "wearing the same exact shoes" as yourself. I have a huge project to work with and no CakePHP knowledge. I tried to start with a plugin like many have suggested, but quickly got lost. Now a couple of months into learning CakePHP, this is what I would suggest you do:

- Read the manual entirely (I downloaded this [COPY](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0ByNCj4MHL2TRZTY4N2NhZDQtOGQ5Mi00NGI1LTg1YzktNDI5MjdiN2YyYTRh&hl=en) and ordered it only as a manual)
- Place sticky markers on the pages and sections you feel you need to reference back
- Use a notebook to create your database structure as detailed as possible and use [CAKEAPP](http://cakeapp.com) to make them all come together. Use as much time as you need since the Database is the most important section of your app. CakeAPP allows you to set your app relantionships as well. Pretty neat!
- Download the SQL code from CAKEAPP and dump it into your MySQL Database
- Use Cake Bake to generate all your Models and Controllers (Change them later if necessary)
- Create your main site layout (default.ctp)
- Manually create all your other Views.

At this stage, DO NOT look at plugins. Plugins will make you lazy and prevent you from learning CakePHP. After you got your main application structure going, you can then look at plugins to beef it up. Looking at plugins this early in your game will only slow you down. Also, look at tutorials online and Q&A like STACKOVERFLOW's. Most importantly, read the Manual

BTW, I am still working on my Database to make sure, from the get go everything is as close to what I need as possible.